# Models in Tensorflow Federated get stucked at 0.1 accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow-federated

I'm trying train a federated model for the mnist dataset. I am using the code avaible at https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/simulations for the setup.
The dataset version being used is the the one from keras (not the federated version from leaf that is used in tff). I'm making a partition of it, saving it on a dictionary and implementing my ClientData instance with `tff.simulation.datasets.TestClientData`.
Applying this change works just fine. However, if I change the model from the simulation, every round gives me a ~0.1 accuracy.

The model in the tutorial is as simple as it can get, an input layer of 28*28=784 neurons stacked over an output layer of dim 10 with Softmax activation:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(784,)), 
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, kernel_initializer='zeros'),
  tf.keras.layers.Softmax(),
])
```

And the new model is a cnn:

```
 model = tf.keras.Sequential(
        [
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
                16,
                8,
                strides=2,
                padding="same",
                activation="relu",
                input_shape=(28, 28, 1),
            ),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 1),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
                32, 4, strides=2, padding="valid", activation="relu"
            ),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 1),
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
        ]
    )
```

Accuracy changed from round to round on the first case, increasing, reaching 0.94 quite fast.
On the second case I ran it for about 240 rounds with 3 fixed clients, 20k elements each, 10 epochs, batch size 32. Still couldn't get out of the ~0.1 accuracy and loss of ~2.3

The model works fine for this dataset. I already tested it on a centrilized version and a federated version using Flower framework reaching 0.99 accuracy. But for some reason I can't make it work on tff.

Environment:
MacOs BigSur
tensorflow==2.8.0
tensorflow-federated==0.22.0

I expect the metrics and loss to change more. Could it be that there is a problem with using other Models?

Full code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10, mnist
import numpy as np

EPOCHS = 10
BATCH_SIZE = 32

# ROUND_CLIENTS <= NUM_CLIENTS
ROUND_CLIENTS = 3
NUM_CLIENTS = 3

NUM_ROUNDS = 400

    
def make_client(num_clients,X, y):
    total_image_count = len(X)
    image_per_set = int(np.floor(total_image_count/num_clients))

    client_train_dataset = collections.OrderedDict()
    for i in range(1, num_clients+1):
        client_name = i-1
        start = image_per_set * (i-1)
        end = image_per_set * i

        print(f"Adding data from {start} to {end} for client : {client_name}")
        data = collections.OrderedDict((('label', y[start:end]), ('pixels', X[start:end])))
        client_train_dataset[client_name] = data
    
    train_dataset = tff.simulation.datasets.TestClientData(client_train_dataset)
    
    return train_dataset


def preprocess(X: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray):
    """Basic preprocessing for MNIST dataset."""
    X = np.array(X, dtype=np.float32) / 255
    X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], 28, 28, 1))

    y = np.array(y, dtype=np.int32)
    y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=10)

    return X, y


(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
(X_train, y_train) = preprocess(X_train, y_train)
(X_test, y_test) = preprocess(X_test, y_test)

mnistFedTrain = make_client(NUM_CLIENTS,X_train,y_train)

def map_fn(example):
    return collections.OrderedDict(
      x=example['pixels'], 
        y=example['label'])


def client_data(client_id):
    ds = mnistFedTrain.create_tf_dataset_for_client(mnistFedTrain.client_ids[client_id])
    return ds.repeat(EPOCHS).shuffle(500).batch(BATCH_SIZE).map(map_fn)


train_data = [client_data(n) for n in range(ROUND_CLIENTS)]
element_spec = train_data[0].element_spec

def create_cnn_model() -> tf.keras.Model:
    """Returns a sequential keras CNN Model."""
    return tf.keras.Sequential(
        [
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
                16,
                8,
                strides=2,
                padding="same",
                activation="relu",
                input_shape=(28, 28, 1),
            ),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 1),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
                32, 4, strides=2, padding="valid", activation="relu"
            ),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 1),
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
        ]
    )

def model_fn():
    model = create_cnn_model()
    return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
      model,
      input_spec=element_spec,
      loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(
                from_logits=True, reduction=tf.losses.Reduction.NONE
            ),
      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()]
    )


trainer = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
    model_fn, client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(0.02))


def evaluate(num_rounds=NUM_ROUNDS):
    state = trainer.initialize()
    for i in range(num_rounds):
        t1 = time.time()
        state, metrics = trainer.next(state, train_data)
        t2 = time.time()
        print('\n Round {r}: metrics {m}, round time {t:.2f} seconds'.format(
            m=metrics['train'], r=i, t=t2 - t1))

t1 = time.time()
evaluate(NUM_ROUNDS)
t2 = time.time()

print('Seconds:',t2 - t1,' = Minutes:', (t2 - t1)/60)
```

I've had a similar problem with other models as well, e.g.  MobileNetV2 implemented in tf for cifar10:
`model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2((32, 32, 3), classes=10, weights=None)

Comment: In the code, after `trainer` is created using `tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process` is `trainer.next` ever called? This is needed to actually execute a step of FedAvg. Try looking at the [Federated Learning for Image Classification](tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification) tutorial

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Yes, after defining the trainer, the function evaluate (which is called with after) is defined, which implements the training for loop, inside it I have the `trainer.next`. This gives back the state to be used in the next iteration. Plus the metrics are printed (there I see that there is no improvement)

Comment: Trying adding `print(state)` to see if the model weights are changing each round (i.e. call to `next`). Also using `tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(..., model_update_aggregation_factory=tff.learning.robust_aggregator(zeroing=False, clipping=False, add_debug_measurements=True))` will add addition metrics that compute statistics on the norms of each client, which can be used to see if the clients are sending useful updates back to the server.

Comment: Hello, I could solve the problem stated here, in the end I believe it had to do with not having the right parameters on the model, in correspondance to the format of the data. I explain more on the github [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/issues/2768). I ran into another problem now, similar but this time only when evaluating. This is the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72484653/problem-when-evaluating-a-model-in-tensorflow-federated-accuracy-stucked-at-0-1). I would appreciate any help with it :) Thanks!