# Problem when evaluating a model in tensorflow federated. Accuracy stucked at 0.1 only on evaluation

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow-federated

I have a model implemented in tensorflow federated, trained to solve a classification problem on the cifar10 dataset. The dataset is made with the TestClientData.

The model is a MobileNetV2 from the module `tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2`. I initialize a state with the data and model in the proper form and call to `state.next` on each iteration, plus the training and test metrics are printed. Training metrics show improvement, however test metrics get stucked at 0.1 accuracy and the loss is stucked as well.

Test is done by defining a keras dummy model of the same architecture and specifications, which receives the weights from the state via `state.model.assign_weights_to(keras_model)`.

I've been careful to use the same loss, optimizer and accuracy on the federated model and the centralized keras model used for evaluation. I'll add a print of what I get from the training loop, I print some weights of the state and the corresponding ones on the keras model just to check that the weights assignment works, and it does. I don’t know what else to check.

```
-------------------------------ROUND 0 ------------------------------------
Initial weights in state: [-0.00721832  0.01982944  0.08157757]

 Train metrics OrderedDict([('sparse_categorical_accuracy', 0.21346854), ('loss', 2.220433), ('num_examples', 49998), ('num_batches', 1563)]), round time 81.32 seconds

After training weights in state: [-0.00548685  0.01842782  0.0898697 ]

Initial weights in dummy model: tf.Tensor([0.12715222 0.00962208 0.1222005 ], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)

Weights in dummy model after assign weights: tf.Tensor([-0.00548685  0.01842782  0.0898697   0.0580997   0.00205497], shape=(5,), dtype=float32)

 Test metrics [2.3025963306427, 0.10000000149011612]
-------------------------------ROUND 1 ------------------------------------
Initial weights in state: [-0.00548685  0.01842782  0.0898697 ]

 Train metrics OrderedDict([('sparse_categorical_accuracy', 0.27069083), ('loss', 1.9941559), ('num_examples', 49998), ('num_batches', 1563)]), round time 80.71 seconds

After training weights in state: [0.00415337 0.01833635 0.1140746 ]

Initial weights in dummy model: tf.Tensor([ 0.03019264 -0.0810149  -0.01419063], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)

Weights in dummy model after assign weights: tf.Tensor([ 0.00415337  0.01833635  0.1140746   0.05260698 -0.00449031], shape=(5,), dtype=float32)

 Test metrics [2.3026626110076904, 0.10000000149011612]
-------------------------------ROUND 2 ------------------------------------
Initial weights in state: [0.00415337 0.01833635 0.1140746 ]

 Train metrics OrderedDict([('sparse_categorical_accuracy', 0.299912), ('loss', 1.8942232), ('num_examples', 49998), ('num_batches', 1563)]), round time 82.39 seconds

After training weights in state: [0.01262705 0.03320389 0.0952585 ]

Initial weights in dummy model: tf.Tensor([0.12944148 0.07921356 0.11308451], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)

Weights in dummy model after assign weights: tf.Tensor([0.01262705 0.03320389 0.0952585  0.02912883 0.00987563], shape=(5,), dtype=float32)

 Test metrics [2.3031070232391357, 0.10000000149011612]
```

------------CODE------------------

The setup is like this:

```
EPOCHS = 1
BATCH_SIZE = 32

# ROUND_CLIENTS <= NUM_CLIENTS
ROUND_CLIENTS = 3
NUM_CLIENTS = 3

NUM_ROUNDS = 3

    
def make_client(num_clients,X, y):
    total_image_count = len(X)
    image_per_set = int(np.floor(total_image_count/num_clients))

    client_train_dataset = collections.OrderedDict()
    for i in range(1, num_clients+1):
        client_name = i-1
        start = image_per_set * (i-1)
        end = image_per_set * i

        print(f"Adding data from {start} to {end} for client : {client_name}")
        data = collections.OrderedDict((('label', y[start:end]), ('pixels', X[start:end])))
        client_train_dataset[client_name] = data
    
    train_dataset = tff.simulation.datasets.TestClientData(client_train_dataset)
    
    return train_dataset

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
cifarFedTrain = make_client(NUM_CLIENTS,X_train,y_train)

def map_fn(example):
    return collections.OrderedDict(
      x=example['pixels'], 
        y=example['label']
    )


def client_data(client_id):
    ds = cifarFedTrain.create_tf_dataset_for_client(cifarFedTrain.client_ids[client_id])
    return ds.repeat(EPOCHS).shuffle(500).batch(BATCH_SIZE).map(map_fn)


train_data = [client_data(n) for n in range(ROUND_CLIENTS)]
element_spec = train_data[0].element_spec

OPTIMIZER = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
LOSS = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
METRICS=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()]

def model_fn():
    model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2((32, 32, 3), classes=10, weights=None)
    return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
            model,
            input_spec=element_spec,
            loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), 
            metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()]
            )


trainer = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn, client_optimizer_fn=lambda:tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())
```

The function performing the training-evaluation loop is this one, I call on the function on 3 rounds, 3 fixed clients and 1 epoch per client:

```
def evaluate(state, num_rounds=NUM_ROUNDS): 
    state = trainer.initialize()
    
    for i in range(num_rounds):
        print(f"-------------------------------ROUND {i} ------------------------------------")
        
        print("Initial weights in state:",state.model.trainable[0][0][0][0][:3])
        t1 = time.time()
        state, metrics = trainer.next(state, train_data)
        t2 = time.time()
        print('\n Train metrics {m}, round time {t:.2f} seconds'.format(
            m=metrics['train'], t=t2 - t1))
        
        print("\nAfter training weights in state:",state.model.trainable[0][0][0][0][:3])
        
        model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2((32, 32, 3), classes=10, weights=None, classifier_activation='softmax')
        
        OPTIMIZER = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
        LOSS = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
        METRICS=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()]

        model.compile(OPTIMIZER, LOSS, METRICS)
        print("\nInitial weights in dummy model:",model.weights[0][0][0][0][:3])

        
        
        state.model.assign_weights_to(model)  # Update model with the latest parameters
        
        print("\nWeights in dummy model after assign weights:",model.weights[0][0][0][0][:5])
        metrics_test = model.evaluate(test_data, test_labels, verbose = False)
          
        print('\n Test metrics {m}'.format(m=metrics_test))
    return state, model
```

Comment: What version of TFF is being used?

Comment: Hey, it's 0.20.0